# How to sum the elements of a n-ary Haskell Tree?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, tree

I am new in Haskell Programming and I have tried to code  and manipulate a Haskell n-ary tree defined as

```
data Tree = Empty | Node Integer [Tree]
```

I want to write a `sum` function for this tree structure, but I did not figure it out. The function I coded is here:

```
sumall Empty = 0

sumall (Node a (x:xy) ) = a + (sumall x)
```

Input: `(Node 5 [Node 2 [Node 1 [Empty]],Node 8 [Node 7 [Node 6 [Empty]],Node 12 [Node 10 [Node 9 [Empty]],Node 13 [Node 15 [Empty]]]]] )`

The result = 8.

How to develop this function to sum all the elements in this tree? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think about how to sum the elements of a list.

Answer (score 3):

```
import qualified Data.Foldable as F

instance F.Foldable Tree where
    foldMap f Empty = mempty
    foldMap f (Node a ts) = mconcat $ f a : map (F.foldMap f) ts

sumall = F.sum
```

without Foldable you would do something like

```
sumall Empty = 0
sumall (Node a ts) = a + foldr (+) 0 (map sumall ts)
```

Comment: Tree is not a Foldable - it doesn't even have the correct kind.

Comment: And of course `foldr (+) 0 x` is just a worse way to write `sum x`.

Comment: @user2407038, indeed. I didn't paste in my `data Tree a` that I was coding against.